# Need for more concatenated roles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Why are there in `biblatex` (e.g. using authortitle-comp in the bibliography) no concatenated roles when Person X is *only* annotator and the author of the introduction? In other words, I get often

> Author, *Book title*. With annotations by John Doe. With an introduction by John Doe. Oxford: 2001.

Why is it not possible to have

> Author, *Book title*. With an introduction and annotations by John Doe. Oxford: 2001.

Such concatenated roles are not defined in the documentation of `biblatex` (http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf -- see esp. "4.9.2.3 Concatenated Editor Roles, Expressed as Functions").

Comment: Could you please add a MWE? That helps us help you.

Comment: I am not quite sure how an MWE should help if it is already clear from the biblatex documentation that such concatenated roles just do not exist.

Comment: If you need help to implement this particular behaviour I would need to see an MWE since the exact details depend on the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to have all kinds of combined roles. Not all possible combinations of concatenated roles are defined and supported by default, though. This is simply because the maintenance of such a huge number of strings place would quite a burden on the developers and many of those combinations are not encountered that often out there in the wild.

You can easily extend the system yourself. It might not be enough, however, to simply define the missing strings yourself with `\NewBibliographyString` and `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`/`\DefineBibliographyStrings`, you may also have to modify some bibmacros involved in name printing, but this depends on the style.

See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/390